Changing the 'compilerRunTimeoutMs' timeout variable on Azure Quantum Resource Estimator
Is there any way to change the variable 'compilerRunTimeoutMs' so that I can increase the timeout for Azure Quantum Resource Estimator. The only way that seems to be an option currently is to build the package from source but I wanted to see if there was another way?

If you're running Resource Estimation via the VS Code extension, then it is hard coded to 5 minutes currently. If you need a higher timeout there, we could make that a configurable setting. (Just open an issue on https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp and we'll get to it).
You can also run the Resource Estimator via the Python API, which doesn't have a timeout. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/overview-resources-estimator if not familiar with that method and it might be a solution.
